# Getting 4 top elemental fusion spells with Ultimate personae?

Tags: persona-2-eternal-punishment

I like always having access to the top 4 elemental (water, wind, fire, earth) fusions (Vain Splash, Giga Cyclone, Meltdown, Last Quake) without switching personas in Persona 2 Eternal Punishment. What spell cards do I need to use to have all of these fusions available with the Ultimate persona set (Artemis, Astria, Hyperion, Prometheus, Apollo)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula for top elemental spells is

- Element;
- Complimentary element (fire+earth, water+wind);
- Maha element.

To have access to all of these fusions, your personae need to have 2 of each fire, earth, water and wind spells, with at most 1 pair of complimentary elements on the same persona and at least 1 spell being of maha (group) variety.

The Ultimate personae have the following elemental spells:

- Artemis: none;
- Astria: wind;
- Hyperion: maha fire;
- Prometheus: earth (via mutation);
- Apollo: maha fire.

That's 0 water, 1 wind, 1 earth and 2 fire, thus we need to add 2 water, 1 wind and 1 earth. To satisfy the above criteria, we must imbue the following spells to our Ultimate personae:

- Maha wind to Artemis;
- Maha water to Astria;
- Maha earth to Hyperion;
- Maha water to Prometheus.

You can replace 1 maha water with plain water if you are skint, in which case the maha version should go on the character with the least agility.

Apollo doesn't get a spell card because he comes pre-summoned.

Your ability to perform Meltdown and Last Quake will depend on Prometheus getting his earth mutation spells, thus equipping Baofu with luck-increasing items and Mutation gear is very much recommended.

Bonus: Ultimate personae are intrinsically able to perform the interesting Nuclear Crush fusion, which goes as follows:

- Nuclear (Hyperion, Apollo);
- Almighty (Artemis, Prometheus);
- Heat Kaiser (Hyperion, Apollo).

You will also have access to Storm Nightmare (kills most enemies outright with wind):

- Wind (Artemis)
- Almighty (Prometheus);
- Twinkle Nebula (Astria).

And the ever-popular Dragon Cross fusion, the special fusion spell available only to Ultimate personae:

- Wiseman Snap (Prometheus);
- Twinkle Nebula (Astria);
- Crescent Mirror (Artemis);
- Justice Shot (Hyperion);
- Nova Cyther (Apollo);